# vba word select columns in a table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I add a table in word with 3 columns and 2 rows. I change the width of the first column and want the other two to distribute even.

I fail to understand how to select the columns. I tried this, but it fails

```
Sub selectCells()
Set aRange = Selection.Tables(1).Range( _
    Selection.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Start, _
    Selection.Tables(1).Cell(1, 3).Range.End)    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to select the column.

You can use `Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1).SetWidth 25` for example.

You can use the Object Explorer and online documentation to help you, for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.column.setwidth